# How does Berkeley distinguish between illusion and reality and what are his arguments?

Tags: idealism, berkeley

Does anyone know that how does he explains the effects of mind altering drugs according to his ideology? For example If God is the master perceiver, Does God also perceive the pink elephant or the melting room with a person who is under LSD?

Comment: Why should it be a problem that a product of God's mind affects human mind?

Comment: @Conifold Would you like to go to a hospital and say that pink elephants are real as everything else?

Comment: I am trying to see what you are getting at. If someone is an Idealist, asserting that things occur in the mind and not in a physical realm, then how can a non-mind, physical substance affect the mind, yes? What would knowing this affect something to do with Berkeley specifically? Why is he important?

Comment: How is this any more a problem for Berkeley than anyone else?

Comment: See [George Berkeley](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/berkeley/#3): "Perhaps the most obvious objection to idealism is that it makes real things no different from imaginary ones—both seem fleeting figments of our own minds, rather than the solid objects of the materialists. Berkeley replies that the distinction between real things and chimeras retains its full force on his view. One way of making the distinction is suggested by his argument for the existence of God, examined above: Ideas which depend on our own finite human wills are not (constituents of) real things. 1/2

Comment: Not being voluntary is thus a necessary condition for being a real thing, but it is clearly not sufficient, since hallucinations and dreams do not depend on our wills, but are nevertheless not real. Berkeley notes that the ideas that constitute real things exhibit a steadiness, vivacity, and distinctness that chimerical ideas do not. The most crucial feature that he points to, however, is order. The ideas imprinted by the author of nature as part of rerum natura occur in regular patterns, according to the laws of nature. They constitute a coherent real world." 2/2

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA that answer should be an answer, not a comment

Comment: If God is the master perceiver, Does God also perceive the pink elephant or the melting room with a person who is under LSD?

Comment: If God is all-knowing, then knows what is going on in minds, yes. Is this a problem? What definition of all-knowing would be suitable?

Comment: @ScottRowe So is God the one who guatantees the drugs work since all minds and everyone perception cohere according to Berkeley?

Comment: If God is all-powerful, then assures that everything 'works' as intended.

Comment: @ScottRowe thats true,  the problem is related with reality. According to him room is really melting because God is perceiving.

Comment: So what does 'really' mean in this case?

Comment: Imagine Berkeley is under LSD, he sees pink elephants and his room melted. He has no other option rather than accepting this mental representations as "real" as everyday life.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Berkeley draws the distinction between illusion (he says "chimeras") and reality by specifying the ideas that are to be considered "real". He does this in section 33 of the *Treatise*.

For him, illusions occur when there is something that we perceive, but we are misled about what it is that we perceive. The classic example is the bent stick in water. When we imagine things, we have invented them. So illusions are a problem for Berkeley, but he doesn't notice because he confuses them with what we imagine. Chimeras, of course, are mythical beasts, but he means "imaginary".

LSD hallucinations are a problem for Berkeley, for just the reason that you suppose.

I think that Berkeley would say that the ideas of taking LSD are regularly followed by certain "chimeras". He allows that we can notice regularities in our ideas, when one idea follows on from another (in his view, it is God that maintains these). So he would explain that it is God who preserves the causal regularity that we notice when we have taken LSD. I think he would maintain however that it is us that creates the actual specific chimeras, rather than God.

Whether he thinks that God also perceives what we imagine, I couldn't say.

Comment: Ludwig V Thank you for your good answer. Its well explained and I totally agree.

Comment: Excellent. I'm no supporter of Berkeley. Just a bit of a nerd about understanding exactly what his arguments amount to. Which is no easy task.

Comment: Ludwig V - I have very doubts about him. First of all he was a non objective, speculator fanatic theist. All his arguments were to debunk materialism and deism. To disprove Locke was his main motivation as well. All this qualities of him makes me to think that he was not honest person at all.

Comment: I don't much like him as a person. He was a political conservativ as well. Some people think that was the real motivation for his thinking. But many people have thought that his arguments are correct or nearly correct. So there's a reason to engage with them.